# TypeScript TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'

Tags: typescript, tslint

I have this code:

```
const expressionAttributeValues = {};
expressionAttributeValues[`:${status}`] = status; // TSLinst error
// status is a string
```

and I got that TSlint error:

```
 TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.
```

What is wrong in that line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hint to the compiler that the type of `expressionAttributeValues` is a key–value mapping from a `string` to a `string`, i.e.

```js
const expressionAttributeValues: { [key: string]: string } = {};
```

Answer (score 5):

When defining `const expressionAttributeValues = {}`, you don't give an explicit type, so the compiler implicitly assumes the value you assign is the type. In this case, you assign `{}`, so an empty object. It's as if you would type it like this: `const expressionAttributeValues: {} = {}`.

Now an empty object that has no properties has no keys, by definition.

Next, you try to access the object's property `:${status}`. As the compiler now believes that `expressionAttributeValues` can *only* be an object without any properties, it complains.

The primitive and not-so-elegant solution would be to just type `expressionAttributeValues` as `any`: `const expressionAttributeValues: any = {}`. This will stop the compiler warning, as now `expressionAttributeValues` can literally be anything, and therefore have any property.

The more elegant approach would be, if possible, to more explicitly type `expressionAttributeValues` and `:${status}`.

For example:

```
interface MyType {
  a?: string;
  b?: string;
  c?: string;
}
const expressionAttributeValues: MyType = {};
const property: keyof MyType = 'a';
console.log(expressionAttributeValues[property]);
```

A minimum definition ("all keys are valid, and their property values are all strings") could also be:

```
type MyType {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you initialized the const `expressionAttibuteValues` with empty object and did not provide a type for that const, the TS compiler automatically assumes that `expressionAttributeValues`is of type empty object. Which is why it is complaining about accessing a property from within it. Either add a type or `any` to `expressionAttributeValues`