# Typescript expression has any value by default

Tags: typescript

I have this interface, implemented below:

```
interface Commands {
  copy: any;
  move: any;
}

const commands: Commands = {
  copy: require("./copyDocument"),
  move: require("./moveDocument"),
}
```

And i want to run the functions linked by copy and move with the following code:

```
const result = await commands[command_type]();
```

Where command_type is a string with the name of the command ( copy/move)
But i get the following errors:

TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'Commands'

How could i fix this one?

Comment: Sounds like this might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63676021/typescript-ts7053-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-ty

Comment: What does `command_type` look like and how do you define it?

Comment: @AndréKrosby, actually, i simplified there, command_type should be req.body.action , which is the action param from the body of an http request

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate issues:

1. You've told TypeScript that the value of `copy` and `move` is `any`, but you want to be able to call it like a function.
2. You want to use an arbitrary string (`command_type`) to index into `commands`, but since an arbitrary string might be *anything* (not just `"copy"` or `"move"`), you can't use an arbitrary string for that (directly) with your current interface in a typesafe fashion.

To address the type issue, you'd specify a function type instead of `any`, so TypeScript knows they're functions. For instance, you might use `() => Promise<Something>` for a function that takes no arguments and returns a promise (explicitly, or by being an `async` function).

To address the indexing issue, you have two choices:

- Don't let `command_type` be any string, make it the types of `command`'s properties: `keyof Commands`. To do that, you might have either a [type predicate function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), a type assertion function, or both. Here's what they look like:

  ```typescript
  // Type predicate function, returns boolean for whether `type` is valid
  function isCommandType(type: string): type is keyof Commands {
       return type === "copy" || type === "move";
  }

  // Type assertion function, throws an error if `type` is invalid
  function assertIsCommandType(type: string): asserts type is keyof Commands {
       if (!isCommandType(type)) { // Or you could repeat the logic from above
           throw new Error(`Expected "copy" or "move", got ${JSON.stringify(type)}`);
       }
  }
  ```

  Then if we start with any string (say, `req.body.action` as you mentioned it in a comment), you might use the type predicate function:

  ```
  const command_type = req.body.action;
  if (isCommandType(command_type)) {
       // Here, TypeScript knows that `command_type` is a valid key for `Commands`
       const result = await commands[command_type]();
       // ...
  }
  ```

  ...or you might use the type assertion function to get an error instead:

  ```
  const command_type = req.body.action;
  assertIsCommandType(command_type);
  // Here, TypeScript knows that `command_type` is a valid key for `Commands`
  const result = await commands[command_type]();
  // ...
  ```
- Alternatively, if you want `command_type` to be any string, your interface would be:

  ```typescript
  interface Commands {
       [key: string]: () => Promise<Something>;
  //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−− allows any string
  }
  ```

  If you do that, then `commands[command_type]` will be `(() => void)|undefined` (the `undefined` is because the string may not match any property). Your call would be:

  ```
  const result = await commands[command_type]?.();
  // Optional chaining −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^
  ```

  ...and `result` would be `undefined | Something` (since the optional chaining will result in `undefined` if `commands[command_type]` is `undefined` or `null`).

  Or you could separate access from call, so TypeScript knows you've handled the `undefined`:

  ```
  const command = commands[command_type];
  if (command) {
       const result = await command();
       // ...
  }
  ```

  There, `result` will be `Something` (if the return type is `Promise<Something>`).

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer, could you show me how the commands would look like if it was written specifically for copy and move commands?

Comment: @randomusernamessssss - No worries, I've updated the answer to expand the first bullet point about `keyof Commands`.