# React select onChange value Type

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, react-select

```js
 <Select
        
        options={options}
        value={selectedBusinessList}
        isMulti
        placeholder="Select Business"
        onChange={(value: any) => setSelectedBusinessList(value)}
        onInputChange={query => {
          if (query) {
            setOptions([]);
            fetchBusiness(query, { limit: 10, offset: 0 });
          }
        }}
      />
```

What should be type of onChange event value.

Here each value is of

type OptionType = { label : string; value:string}

setSelectedBusinessList() is taking argument of type OptionType

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
onChange={(e: any) => setSelectedBusinessList(e.target.value)}
```

Comment: Unable to add any type because of ts-lint error

Comment: check this :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63676021/typescript-ts7053-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-ty